# Why do I get AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'zipcode'?

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'zipcode'
```

I get this error when the user fills out a form to sell an item.

Here are my views:

```
def get_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = SellForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            form=f.save(commit=False)
            form.author = request.user
            form.zipcode = request.user.zipcode
            form.pubdate = datetime.datetime.now
            form.save()
    else:
        f = SellForm()
    return render(request, 'sell.html', {'form': f})
```

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from django.conf import settings

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    city = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                       max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    coverpic = models.ImageField(upload_to="/site_media/media/covers/", null=True, blank=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.IntegerField(max_length=8)
    zipcode =models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryzipcodes')
    price1 = models.TextField()
    price2 = models.TextField()
    item_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="/site_media/media/items/", null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is my form:

```
class SellForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['headline', 'body_text', 'author', 'pub_date', 'zipcode', 'price1', 'price2', 'item_picture']
```

Am I doing anything wrong with the models?

Comment: where you get this error?

Comment: `zipcode` is attribute of `MyProfile`.

Comment: I have updated the question.  I suspect I am doing something wrong in the get_entry view method.

Comment: please get `SellForm` definition.

Comment: okay here is my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, and even reiterate in your comment, zipcode is an attribute of MyProfile, not of User. So why are you trying to access it on the user? You need to follow the relationship to the profile:

```
form.zipcode = request.user.my_profile.zipcode
```

(Note that "form" is a very bad name for the variable there: what you have is an instance of Entry, so perhaps you should name it accordingly.)